# JavaFX TableView - Resetting the column sorts

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am not looking to disable the sorting of a `TableView` when I click on the column header. But I am looking for a programmatic way to rid all column sorting at any time, as shown below in the screenshot in the ID column. I want that sort arrow gone.

[image]

The reason I need to remove the sorters at any time is because I have features that move searched records to the top, and sorting will mess this up. But I want to allow the user to sort whenever they want when they aren't using this feature.

I've spent probably 45 minutes digging through the `TableView` and `TableColumn` API looking for something that will turn it off. Is there a way to do this without binding to a `SortedList`? I'd prefer not to mess with the items backing the `TableView`, but rather the `TableView` or `TableColumn` itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got some help elsewhere from Jonathan Giles. You can remove the sorts by calling the following

```
tableView.getSortOrder().clear()
```

Unfortunately, I didn't realize the sorters physically modified the backing `ObservableList` of items. So the solution would be to call the above method and  re-order items manually that I've deemed to be the "natural order".